# unwanted <p> tag turns one <a> into two

Tags: html, drupal, hyperlink

I have a `<a>` link with items inside. When I put a `<p>` tag around it, to simulate drupal's line break and paragraph filters that will be applied to my code automatically, The link becomes two links. One link is inside the `<p>` with no children the other is outside with one of the child elements. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

```
<div class="notDrupal srvTileGroup">  
<p>
  <a href="http://www.airforcemedicine.af.mil/" class="notDrupal srvTile shadow2 shadow6h">
    <div class="notDrupal srvTileTxt bAirforce"><!-- <p class="notDrupal">AIR FORCE</p> --></div>
    <img class="notDrupal srvTilePic" src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/256723/BackgroundPattern126Colour.png" alt="air force"></img>
  </a>
</p>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/bjackson2016/pen/AXgKgQ)

Comment: Because you cannot put block level elements inside inline elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not related with Drupal. You had placed a div element inside an anchor. Replace that div with span and you can see your code start working perfect.

For Info please see [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/6fwquL02/)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Also the other <p> tag when uncommented creates the same problem until I replace it with a span as well.

Comment: Because div and p are block element and you should not use them in a inline element like a, span etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I always thought that that was fine because you can put <img> elements in an anchor tag without issue.